# android intellij not resolve method getActionBar() in sliding menu

Tags: android, menu, sliding

1. download sliding menu from this link  [1]: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
   2.import this project to intellij but the method getaction bar cannot resolve

please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using getSupportActionBar() instead.

I assume the library has been built for backwards support with Android, so it's using the Support library.

Comment: thanks for answer  i use support library v4,v8,v13 and use getSupportActionBar()   but not resolve